# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string - Visual Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to insert data into my database using these commands (Homework):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Movies] ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title], [Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (1, 3, N'Titanic', N'James Cameron', N'1997‐06‐21 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title], [Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (2, 1, N'StarWars', N'George Lucas', N'1977-06‐01 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title], [Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (3, 1, N'Jurassic Park', N'Steven Spielberg', N'1993‐06‐17 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title], [Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (4, 4, N'Jaws', N'Steven Spielberg', N'1975-05-30 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title], [Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (5, 3, N'Ghost', N'Jerry Zucker', N'1990‐06-­14 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title], [Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (7, 3, N'Forrest Gump', N'Robert Zemeckis', N'1994‐06‐18 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title], [Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (8, 2, N'Ice Age', N'Chris Wedge', N'2002‐06‐26 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title],[Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (9, 2, N'Shrek', N'AndrewAdamson', N'2001‐06‐25 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title],[Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (10, 1, N'Independence Day', N'Roland Emmerich', N'1996-06-20 00:00:00')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title], [Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (11, 4, N'The Ring', N'Gore Verbinski', N'2002‐06‐26 00:00:00')

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Movies] OFF
```

But it keeps giving me the exception:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

[image]

Comment: Please show your code... or if no code is involved, please remove the `c#` tag as it would be irrelevant. Either way, show the schema.

Comment: Okay fixed. Sorry my mistake their isn't any C# Code involved.

Comment: (And do *all* of these inserts fail? We only need to see one... at the moment we can't tell whether the first one fails or the last...)

Comment: Do you actually have newline characters in the datetime strings, or is that an artifact of how the question is presented here?

Comment: Post the `CREATE TABLE` script, otherwise we have no idea if you have defined your tabel correctly and everything else is just guess work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on `CAST` and `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

So in your sample code - does this insert work? (*I added the `T` separator between the `YYYY-MM-DD` date and the time portion*)

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title], [Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (11, 4, N'The Ring', N'Gore Verbinski', N'2002‐06‐26T00:00:00')
```

Or if you're only interested in the date itself (not the time) - try this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Movies] ([Id], [CategoryId], [Title], [Director], [DateReleased]) 
VALUES (11, 4, N'The Ring', N'Gore Verbinski', N'20020626')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'2002‐06‐26 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Didn't work but thanks anyway :) Just threw me the same error.

Comment: Can you gimme CREATE TABLE script ?

Comment: what type of DateReleased ?